# Invalid namespace in Visual Studio 2017 Set Report Parameter

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have an issue with adding parameters to a report. Whenever I try to set a parameter the report displays with an error. If I don't add any parameter the report works fine but there is no data since the stored procedure requires some parameters. Here is part of the code that has the error.

```
prms.Add(new ReportParameter("EndDate", endDate.ToShortDateString()));
prms.Add(new ReportParameter("StartDate", startDate.ToShortDateString()));
reportviewer.viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(prms);
```

The error that I receive when running the project is:

Microsoft.Reporting.DefinitionInvalidException: The definition of the report '' is invalid. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services. The report definition may have been created with a later version of Reporting Services, or contain content that is not well-formed or not valid based on Reporting Services schemas. Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.

Answer (score 3):

installing the nuget package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms 
version 14.0.0.0 should be enough to fix your problems

note that installing this nuget package will install the CLRTypes for SQL server 2017

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by installing the following files:

Microsoft Report Projects for Visual Studio
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio

Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer for Visual Studio
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SqlReportingServices.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001

Report Viewer control
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2016/11/30/report-viewer-2016-control-update-now-available/

Integrating Reporting Services Using ReportViewer Controls - Get Started
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started

I found this solution at the following page: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/60277/microsoftreportingwebformslocalprocessingexception.html

Regards

Comment: Thanks, for your info. I handed over the project to another guy. I don't know if he fixed it but. I'll confirm with him.

Comment: Worked for me after installing these tools and changing the web.config.

Comment: New link for Rdlc Report Designer for Visual Studio: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001